# Unable to access dotnet via sudo dotnet in CentOS

Tags: .net-core, centos7

I'm using CentOS headless server on azure, & I set up `.Net core` there.
I'm able to access `dotnet --info` but unable to access `sudo dotnet --info`. Provided, I cant access root user.

Comment: Can you provide more information? How did you install .NET Core? what does `echo $PATH` and ` sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH' ` say? What do you mean by "provided I can't access root user"?

Comment: Oh. And what does `which dotnet` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking deeper into sudo [here](https://superuser.com/questions/548508/why-cant-i-sudo-some-commands-e-g-vim), I found out that, When running sudo, many systems are configured to clear the environment of all non-whitelisted values, and to reset the PATH variable to a sanitized value.

This was actually clearing out the `PATH` for dotnet, restricting the command to not be executed with sudo.
For the solution, You will find `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` in `/etc/sudoers`. Removing that line from sudoers file will resolve that issue.

You can access `sudoers file` by `visudo` command.