.NET location: Not found
I have looked around at similar questions and found no answers for myself. I am using Raspberry Pi Zero 2.
I had written a web app using .NET Core 6 and deployed to the Pi which is using debian OS. I have created a service to start this app. It has worked for months.
I then upgraded my web app to .NET Core 8. I update the .NET on the pi.
If I run it through a service, I get the error mentioned in the title.
If I run it directly in the directory and call the 'executable' it errors if I preface it with 'sudo'. But if I remove the 'sudo' it works fine.
This is the service error:

This is the info regarding my .NET install:

These is my environment variables:

This is my service:
[Unit]
Description=RealiseMotion Loader
 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/RealiseMotion/web/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/RealiseMotion/web/RealiseMotion.Client 10001
#WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin/RealiseMotion/Loader/
#ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/RealiseMotion/Loader/RealiseMotion.Loader

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

The thing is I have to run this service as a root user.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74296809/dotnet-path-not-found-when-run-program-with-sudo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445330/unable-to-access-dotnet-via-sudo-dotnet-in-centos

@HansPassant Thank you very much.  Very useful but neither approaches worked for me.  It is really weird

I find weird that you have DOTNET_ROOT=/lib/dotnet when dotnet --info reports everything being installed in /usr/lib/dotnet. Mind checking if there is a symbolic link in place ? Or even adjusting the environment variable to the path reported by dotnet ?

Btw, the documentation about DOTNET_ROOT
